# how to update bundled js on save in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

in my asp.net core project I have `bundleconfig.json`:

```
"outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
"inputFiles": [
  "wwwroot/js/a.js",
  "wwwroot/js/b.js
],
```

and I reference the bundle in `_Layout.cshtml` like this:

```
<script src="~/js/site.min.js"></script>
```

If I edit `a.js` or `b.js` the changes won't go to `site.min.js` until I build the project.

Is it possible to update the bundle (`site.min.js`) on save ?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier#bundling) It should work as-is. It seems as though there are number of different configuration changes you can make to it though through right-clicking on the `bundleconfig.json`. Any possibility you undid one of those options?

Comment: I don't have that when I right click, looks like I need to install the VS extension from your link

Comment: thank you, installing the VS extension did it, now the site.min.js is updated on save. You should add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is enabled through a VS Extension. It looks like you need to install the VS Extension and make sure it is appropriately configured.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier#bundling) it should work as-is. It seems as though there are number of different configuration changes you can make to it though through right-clicking on the bundleconfig.json.